# Same style (eg., Bt Charter, no bold style) between chapter/section/etc and ToC/LoF/LoT

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, formatting

I recently noticed the difference between the chapter/section/subsection font style and those in ToC, and also the style in LoF and LoT, it seems that bold style is dominant in the latter. What is the right syntax to change the style of the latter according to the former?

Any pointers are appreciated, thanks in advance,

My code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                        
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

% Change/add ToC/LoF/LoT default settings
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}   % replace 'Contents' by 'Table of Contents'
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}      % add dots for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}      % add dots for chapters
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }    % prefix 'Chapter' to chapter number in 'Table of Contents'
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{6em}           % indentation of chapters
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}       % add 'Page' to ToC

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{The First Section}
\subsection{The First SubSection}
\section{The Next Section}
\subsection{The Second SubSection}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\appendix
\chapter{Tables}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner thanks for the quick reply, please see my edit. The problem I have is the bold font in ToC, LoF and LoT, I want to have all the titles like the chapter "Introduction" (ie. no bold, Bt Charter font).

Comment: As far as I can see, when `\usepackage[bitstream-chater]{mathdesign}` your entire document is set in that specific font family (which is [`mdbch`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign)). So, you may only be interested in removing the **bold**, which is possible via `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}`.

Comment: @Werner thanks for that! it worked for the contents, but the ToC/LoF/LoT titles are still bold, what else should I add to the same command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}` makes your entire document conform to the [`mdbch`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign) font family.

To adjust the **bold**ness of your ToC/LoT/LoF titles, you can add

```
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\normalfont\Huge\mdseries}
\let\cftlottitlefont\cfttoctitlefont
\let\cftloftitlefont\cfttoctitlefont
```

to your preamble. The first command adjusts the series to `\mdseries` for `\cfttoctitlefont` (the original definition is `\normalfont\Huge\bfseries`), while the second and third makes `\cftlottitlefont` and `\cftloftitlefont` equivalent to `\cfttoctitlefont`.

To adjust the **bold**ness of your chapter font styles, then you can redefine `\cftchapfont` to something other than its default `\bfseries`. For example

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
```

or just `\let\cftchapfont\relax` (to make it a no-op).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                        
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% Change/add ToC/LoF/LoT default settings
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\normalfont\Huge\mdseries}
\let\cftlottitlefont\cfttoctitlefont
\let\cftloftitlefont\cfttoctitlefont
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}   % replace 'Contents' by 'Table of Contents'
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}      % add dots for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}      % add dots for chapters
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }    % prefix 'Chapter' to chapter number in 'Table of Contents'
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{6em}           % indentation of chapters
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}       % add 'Page' to ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{The First Section}
\section{The Next Section}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\appendix
\chapter{Tables}

\end{document}
```

Comment: exactly! I recently figured it out `\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\huge}` that seems to do the trick. Thanks Werner.